# Multiple messages to recipient_bcc_maps and sender_bcc_maps with Postfix while using amavis

Tags: server, configuration, email, postfix, mail

I have a problem to configure my postfix. My aim is to have a mail-server
which filters spam and virus mails by using Spamassasin and ClamAV via
amavis. Furthermore i want to archive a copy of each mail in an extra
archive. For this i chose the way to use the recipient_bcc_maps and the
sender_bcc_maps parameters in the /etc/postfix/main.cf to forward a copy of all
incoming and outgoing mails to one archive e-mail-address. The filter with
amavis works fine. And if i disable the filter the forwarding the mails
also works fine.

The Problem I have is if I enable the filtering. In this case each mail I send is send three times to the archive e-mail-address mails which I receive is send two times to the archive.

I suggest that this is cause the mail is received again from amavis but I don't know how I can disable the sender_bcc_maps and recipient_bcc_maps for the re-received mails from amavis. I already tried to add the parameters to the /etc/postfix/master.cf

```
127.0.0.1:10027 inet n - n - - smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o recipient_bcc_maps=
    -o sender_bcc_maps=
    ...
```

But it does not changed anything. I am grateful for any Ideas.
Ulli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `receive_override_options` in your `master.cf` as follows.

```
#/etc/postfix/master.cf
127.0.0.1:10027 inet n - n - - smtpd
   -o content_filter=
   -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
```

- `no_address_mappings`  - will disable canonical address mapping, virtual alias map expansion, address masquerading, and automatic BCC (blind carbon-copy) recipients. This is typically specified BEFORE an external content filter.

More info [here](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#no_address_mappings). Hope that helps.

Comment: thx this is exactly what i needed.